# How do I remove the empty box on the second tr?

Tags: html, html-table

```
td {
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(80, 255, 109);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

<table>

  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">AC</td>
     <td>Del</td>
     <td>+</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>-<td>
```

I get an extra box here

```
</table>
```

When I run this. I get an extra empty box on the end of the second tr.

Comment: Not really sure I understand your problem, but your final closing <td> tag is missing the /

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</td>` tag before you close the table. Try this:

```
td {
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(80, 255, 109);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

<table>

  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">AC</td>
     <td>Del</td>
     <td>+</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>-</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not closing your second tr tag

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">AC</td>
     <td>Del</td>
     <td>+</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>-<td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing `</td>` at `<td>-</td>`

```css
td {
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(80, 255, 109);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">AC</td>
     <td>Del</td>
     <td>+</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
     <td>-</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```